# Fourier transform of convolution with additional dependence

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

There's the well-known identity
$$\widehat{f*g}(\xi)=\hat f(\xi)\hat g(\xi)$$
for, say, $f,g\in\mathcal S$. Does anyone know of an extension of this to a situation like
$$\mathcal F_x\{[f*g(\cdot,x)](x)\}?$$
To be clear what I mean, this would be written as
$$\int e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\int f(t)g(x-t,x)dtdx.$$
It's not clear to me how to treat this because the obvious changes of variable (eg. $x\mapsto x+t$) don't make the integrand separable like in the classical version.

Comment: your second formula is highly unclear, and the 3rd is obviously not simplifiable in general

Comment: @user1952009 Indeed it is an awkward expression to write down. If it is obvious then of course you can explain why in an answer.

Comment: $(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- i \omega x}  f(x) dx)(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- i \omega x}  g(x,x) dx) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- i \omega x}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) g(x-t,x-t) dt dx$ doesn't have any reason to be related to  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- i \omega x}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) g(x-t,x) dt dx$